# How to equally space three code blocks in Squarespace across the full display width?

Tags: javascript, css

Using Squarespace, I want to understand how to use CSS to distribute three code blocks across the entire screen width and have the CSS dynamic to accommodate different screen sizes.

Summary: I have three code blocks on a page in Squarespace.  Each code block is named "codeblock1", "codeblock2" and "codeblock3" (I also identified the block IDs such as #block-be6b8b856f896c0d000) for each codeblock.  Each code block results in displaying one photo.  I'd like to take advantage of using the entire screen width and would like the code blocks to equally span the entire screen width, and have this dynamic to accommodate different screen sizes.

I'd like to understand how to control this using CSS.  For example, I've been able to move the left-most codeblock to the left using code (changing the left margin to -300 versus 0):

```
#block-48747d3bb62b559a0000 {
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    max-width: 100%;
```

However, this doesn't work if I change the browser size, and it also doesn't work for the other two code blocks. Perhaps if someone could specifically explain how to do this in SS (in particular explaining where code should go) that would be fantastic.

**EDIT:

Thanks for the fast responses!  This worked using the solution by @Chris.  I made the following modifications to get the layout that I was looking for:

```
.image {
  width: 33vw
  position: absolute;

}

#block-3e9110aac8284e2c1234 {
  left: -15vw;
  width: 130%;

}

#block-48747d3bb62b559a5678 {
  left: -5vw;
  width: 130%  

}

#block-be6b8b856f896c0d9102 {
  left: 5vw;
  width: 130%
}
```

** Please note: for those not aware, Squarespace has fixed margins for the body of any webpage.  If you want items to span an entire computer screen, you need to modify your CSS to move items to the left or right of the fixed margins.  Using the @Chris solution, the only way I could get the leftmost div to move to the left of the margin was use use a negative vw (-15vw); once I did that, I had to make other modifications to get the divs to equally distribute across the screen (the middle div was "-5vw" and the right-most div was "5vw").  This probably also has to do with the size of each block that I'm distributing - I ended up increasing their size by 130%.

I noticed that this solution caused a new problem: when this page renders on an iPhone, the images are too big (they don't re-size correctly to fit the iPhone screen) and they are sequentially offset left to right (they are not centered).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of using "margin-left", you can just use "left" to position the image. Second of all, you can use "vw" instead of "%" to size the image so that it always has the same width relative to the windows' width. I have tried to make a rough version of this down below

```css
    .image {
  width: 33.33vw;
  position: absolute;
}
.image1 {
  left: 0;
}

.image2 {
  left: 33.33vw;
}

.image3 {
  left: 66.66vw;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image image1">
<img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image image2">
<img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image image3">
```

Comment: your CSS worked using a negative VW to move the first image to the left of the SS margin.   But my images are offset!                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
  .image {
  width: 33vw
  position: absolute;

}

#block-3e9110aac8284e2cABCD {
  left: -10vw;
  width: 130%;

}

#block-48747d3bb62b559aEFGH {
  left: 0vw;
  width: 130%  

}
 #block-be6b8b856f896c0dIJKL {
  left: 10vw;
  width: 130%
}

Comment: @Picasso I am not quite sure what you mean by offset, could you maybe go into details about this? And could you please explain the CSS code that you have commented?

Comment: I tried writing a longer comment with my code and unfortunately the comments are limited to a certain # of characters!  How can I write a longer message?

Comment: In brief, offset means that the three images aren't equally spaced across the screen.  They are close (I tried copying/pasting my code in my message above, for example I used "left: -10vw; width: 130%"; the middle image was "left: 0vw; width: 130%" and the right image was "left 10vw; width: 130%) ... but while they are almost equally spaced across the screen, they aren't equally spaced.

Comment: @Picasso maybe you could make a snippet with your code in your original question so I can get an illustration of the problem

Comment: I just updated my original question with new information.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish that using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is very easy to use and is well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) at this time.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.imageCont {
    width: 33.33%;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageCont">
        <img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image">
    </div>

    <div class="imageCont">
        <img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image">
    </div>

    <div class="imageCont">
        <img src="https://th.thgim.com/opinion/op-ed/article22695424.ece/alternates/FREE_300/9thscience" alt="image" class="image">
    </div>
</div>
```